# How to create a new table that summarises data from another data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame df whose data looks like,

```html
dataset <- data.frame(customer_id = c(12,12,234,234,781,456),
                  Sales_id = c(20013211129, 20013217122, 20013149844, 20013273151, 20013222724, 20013171637),
                  Rev = c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000),
                  Source = c('App', 'Non-App', 'App', 'Non-App', 'Non-App', 'Non-App'))

customer_id |   Sales_id  | Rev | Source
       12     20013211129   1000  App
       12     20013217122   1000  Non-App
       234    20013149844   1000  App
       234    20013273151   1000  Non-App
       781    20013222724   1000  Non-App
       456    20013171637   1000  Non-App
```

I want a table to be created using data of this data frame that shows result as,

```html
........No_of_customers | no_of_orders | total_revenue
App         2                 2               2000
Non-App     4                 4               4000
Total       6                 6               6000
App%        33%               33%              33%
```

Here, the number of customers is on the basis of count of distinct customer_id, number of orders is on the count of distinct sales_id and total is directly the sum total of the preceding two rows.
I'm new to R, so I need some help regarding what functions should I use for this job

Comment: For this kind of stuff you should definitly look into the packages "tidyr" and "dplyr". Be warned, it will take you many hours (weeks really) to learn and get to a point where you can make a table like that. But there is probably no alternative.

Comment: the `ddply` function is good (from the `plyr` package) for data summaries. You can do more than one at once and name them, and group by various other variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution, probably not the best one but it works...

```
## Load Data
customer_id <- c(12,12,34,234,781,456)
Sales_id <- c(20013211129,
              20013217122,
              20013149844,
              20013273151,
              20013222724,
              20013171637)
Rev <- rep(1000, 6)
Source <- c("App", "Non-App", "App", "Non-App", "Non-App", "Non-App")
data <- data.frame(customer_id, Sales_id, Rev, Source, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Create Overview table
library(dplyr)
result <- data %>% 
  group_by(Source) %>% 
  summarise(No_of_customers = length(unique(customer_id)),
            no_of_orders = length(unique(Sales_id)),
            total_revenue = sum(Rev))
temp_res <- result[,-1]
temp_res <- rbind(temp_res, apply(temp_res, 2, sum))
temp_res <- rbind(temp_res, temp_res[1,]/temp_res[3,]*100)
cbind(Cat = c("App", "Non-App", "Total", "App%"), temp_res)
```

However, I do not recomend to put totals and shares as additional row into a data.frame.
Instead I would do something like that...

```
library(tidyr)
result <- result %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Source, names_to = "Cat")

## get Total
result %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(value))

## get Share
result %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarise(App_share = value[Source == "App"] / sum(value))
```